# grunt webpack Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-server'

Tags: gruntjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a grunt setup to bundle my react files using webpack and grunt-webpack. I am not using `webpack-dev-server` but still my grunt is outputting error as `Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-server'`

Here is my grunt file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config.js");

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-webpack");

  grunt.initConfig({
    eslint: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'eslint.json'
      },
      target: ['./react/components/**/*.js','./react/services/**/*.js', './node/source/**/*.js']
    },
    webpack: {
      options: webpackConfig,
      build:{}
    },
    watch: {
      app: {
        files: ['./react/main.js', './react/components/**/*.js','./react/services/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ["webpack"],
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('lint', ['eslint']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['webpack']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

`webpack.config.js` file

```
const path = require('path');
const buildDirectory = './node/static/js/';

module.exports = {
    entry: './react/main.js',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(buildDirectory),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    externals: {
        'cheerio': 'window',
        'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
        'react/lib/ReactContext': true,
    },
    stats: {
        assets: false,
        colors: false,
        modules: false,
        version: false,
        hash: false,
        timings: false,
        chunks: false,
        chunkModules: false
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            },
        }],
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Error output

```
grunt build
Loading "webpack-dev-server.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-server'
Loading "webpack-dev-server.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-dev-server'

Running "webpack:build" (webpack) task


Done.
```

This error gets resolved if I add `webpack-dev-server` package, but I don't want extra dependency in my project.

Packages:

```
"webpack": "^1.13.1",
"grunt-webpack": "^1.0.14",
"grunt": "^1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-eslint": "^19.0.0",
```

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` a dev and peer dependency of `grunt-webpack`.

Comment: Is it really dependent? Cause in the docs its no where mentioned

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://github.com/webpack/grunt-webpack/blob/a69fdfdf7988ccbdd83fd1e6123b2cbcce784739/package.json#L21) and [here](https://github.com/webpack/grunt-webpack/blob/a69fdfdf7988ccbdd83fd1e6123b2cbcce784739/package.json#L37). It should have been installed when you installed `grunt-webpack`, though, or at least should have given a warning that the peer dependency wasn't installed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't know why it didnt installed, I ll try again and see the output.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add it as dependency. Why you don't need it anyway; it seems necessary to in order to run the project in development. That's way NPM allows you to have development dependencies as well. All of the ones that you listed are dev dependencies.

See below:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    // ... more dev dependencies
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // ... more 'normal' dependencies
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  }
```

Comment: Thats not a solution, its kind of hack. If I am not using it then why should I include it inside my project.

Comment: You are using it ... one of the packages that you use, use it. So you have to have a dependency on it. Something requires that modules and including it in your ```package.json``` is not a hack.